# Quick way to see how many people helped across all SE sites

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-exchange, people-reached

Is there a quick way to see how many people I've helped ("reached") across all SE sites?

Answer (score -7):

Your profile page lists the amount of impressions that you have made, using stats on all posts that have a positive score.

On Meta Stack Exchange, [I've reached around 13 thousand people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/289845/zizouz212?tab=topactivity).

Comment: Right; I would like to see that amount for all SE sites without logging in to each one and then clicking on the profile tab for each.

Comment: There's not really a way that I know @RockPaperLizard. You could search the Network profile, but I doubt that the stat is available automatically.